# How handle multiple values in postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a parameter in which comma seperated values are coming. How to handle those in where clause in the query?

Comment: I am using unnest and its working fine when single value is given to me but when multiple values are coming then its not giving me the desired result. My parameter and column datatype is character varying

Comment: To make this a useful question, add your Postgres version, the complete `CREATE FUNCTION` statement you have now (even if it's not working as desired) and an example for a function call with the desired result. Put all defining information into the question, not in comments.

Comment: perhaps use `any` or `all`